# How to perform correlation in loadrunner between the page urls?

Tags: performance, correlation, loadrunner

I am working with HTTP web page requests and i am facing problems in correlation in between urls as below

```
web_custom_request("verifyOtp_2", 
        "URL=http://ip:port/Saving/verifyOtp?mobileNo=1234567890&cardNo=456789876545467&otp=709129&txnType=CUSTOMER_UPDATE", 
        "Method=POST", 
        "Resource=0", 
        "Referer=http://ip:port/Saving/ManageCustomer", 
        "Snapshot=t35.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML", 
        "EncType=plain/text", 
        LAST);
```

Now i want to correlate mobile no,card number in above url,once i tries that url is displaying in Red Color,Please help how to perform this correlation in between urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you capture the response prior to this request which includes the data that you seek. There are multiple mechanical processes for identification and addressing of correlation candidates within LoadRunner.   All of the methods are covered in both the standardized training and the tutorial which ships with the product.  You should also be working with a mentor after training to reinforce the concepts.

If your manager has not committed to your training and a mentor then your manager is not interested in your success in this role.

Comment: Always manager will not help ,i am a self learner and working in small company,if every employee is getting help from managers then there is no need of extra resources for testing only manager can handle individually

Comment: You have been setup to fail. There is really no way to sugar coat this response.  There is a defined path which results in success and then there is a path with a higher than 90% failure rate.  You are on the failure path.  If your company is going to demand that you perform in this role then they owe you training and a mentor for a period until you can be successful.